# How to interpret "dar a" or "dar a conocer"?

Tags: verbos, modismos

I only know "dar" in its literal sense of "to give".

And I know "conocer" in its literal sense of "to know" or "to get to know".

But in reading *Cien años de soledad* I came to this passage:

> ... y con un grande alboroto de pitos y timbales **daban a conocer** los nuevos inventos.

Literally "dar a conocer" would be "to give to know", which doesn't make much sense.

Not only do I not know what it means but I don't know how to parse it. Is "dar a" an idiom or set phrase? Or is "dar a conocer" an idiom or set phrase? Or is it some auxiliary usage of "dar" that I don't know about?

I've looked up both "dar" and "conocer" in my Gran Larouuse bilingual dictionary to no avail.

**How should I parse and understand what's going on in "dar a conocer"?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I understand the difficulty.

**Dar a conocer** is actually an idiom or a figure of speech that is always interpreted as ***To make it known***

This same figure can also be used as **Dar a saber** which has the same meaning.

So in this case the translation of your passage would be:

> ... y con un grande alboroto de pitos y timbales daban a conocer los nuevos inventos.

into

> ... and with great show and noise they **made** their new inventions **known**.